# too many open files while using JAX-WS client

Tags: jax-ws

I am having an application which communicates to a remote web server using a JAX-WS based client. The problem I am facing is that the application is not properly closing the HTTP connections after a request is completed. The sockets are in CLOSED_WAIT state. The out of the lsof -p  is as follows with all the sockets in CLOSED_WAIT:

52u  IPv6            6467002                  TCP gsilin2.india.com:31842->gsilin2.india.com:7073 (CLOSE_WAIT)
 53u  IPv6            6467357                  TCP gsilin2.india.com:31970->gsilin2.india.com:7073 (CLOSE_WAIT)
 54u  IPv6            6467480                  TCP gsilin2.india.com:32015->gsilin2.india.com:7073 (CLOSE_WAIT)
 55u  IPv6            6467368                  TCP gsilin2.india.com:31974->gsilin2.india.com:7073 (CLOSE_WAIT)

Form the above scenario, my understanding is that JAX-WS internally is not closing the underlying HTTP connetions. The following is a code snippet that has been used in the application.

```
    BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider)atuaPortType;
    bindingProvider.getBinding().setHandlerChain(handlerChain);
    Map<String, Object> map=bindingProvider.getRequestContext();  
    .....
    .....  

    map.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, serverurl);
    Map map1 = new HashMap();
    map1.put("Connection", Collections.singletonList("close"));
    map.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, map1);
```

When the application has to send more requests to the web server, the application is being crashed with "too many open files" error. I am not finding any solution.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Chandan Talukdar,
Bangalore, India

Comment: It's closing them just fine; that's not what `CLOSE_WAIT` means.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. But, what I am getting is that after some time - the application will receive an exception with "too many open files" and thsi occurs when the number of sockets in CLOSED_WAIT state has increased.... so , I think the HTTP connections are not getting closed properly by the application (the JAX-WS client) - chandan

Comment: Hi Brian, the application did not contain the Connection=close header initially, and it was using the Keep-Alive Connection header, but still the sockets were in ESTABLISHED state. The sockets state then changed to CLOSED_WAIT after some time and the "too many opne files" issue would occur after some time.. as you mentioned above "all TCP connections go to CLOSED_WAIT" state, so when are the sockets move out of CLOSED_WAIt state? Is it the linux OS who takes care of  it.. And will increasing the number of available handlers to a sufficiently high value help here. chandan

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved by using the latest version of JAX-WS. The JAX-WS libraries provided with java does not close the sockets properly. please follow the below link

[HTTP connection reuse in JAX-WS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522579/http-connection-reuse-in-jax-ws)